# Selenium - error in run test by testRunner

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Hi have problem i create test when i run it from selenium IDE everything is ok, test be passed. When i run my test by selenium testRunner the page was opened but any command eg. clickandwait cannot run in log error "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object". Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue for this in their bug tracker:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=703